# It won't let me connect to my instance's ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, instance

It won't let me connect to the instance's ssh it just keeps loading, I tried to delete it and create it again but nothing, still check the firewall and the ports are not causing an echo.

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer your question because you provide almost no information beyond the facts that you have a problem and you're evidently using Compute Engine. It would be helpful if you were to include the commands that you've tried and the exact errors (not screenshots) that you received. The more information you provide, the easier it will be be for someone to answer your question. Until then, it's likely that others will flag your question.

Comment: Hello Jarvi, welcome to stackoverflow. Unfourtionaly your question is not clear, plz consider reading [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question for members to be able to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the web console built-in client. Clean browser cache, try a different browser, use `gcloud compute ssh` from cli or cloud shell. BTW, if it's an access issue (however you should have received an error in ssh window in this case) - you'll see same problem in command line, if it's a browser issue cli will work.